# How to query data from Firebase with an async call to uid

Tags: firebase, flutter, future

I'm trying to fetch data that belong to the logged in user, however, the "getuserui" is async, for some reason. even though the user is logged in to do stuff inside the app the function still returns a Future....

I've lost count to how many different things i've tried, including .then and such but here's my latest attempt.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 900,
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: () async{
            fireFirestore.instance.collection('properties').where('uid', isEqualTo: await _authService.getUserId()) .snapshots(),
          }, 
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return const Text('Loading...');
            else {
              return ListView.builder( ...............
```

in case you need to see the getUserId():

```
Future<String> getUserId() {
    return _auth.currentUser().then((value) => value.uid.toString());
  }
```

(i've done this method in both the future way (.then) and the async way (async await)

it just tells me `the argument type Future<null> can't be assigned to the parameter type Stream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're passing an async function as a stream, hence your error. Second, you need to wrap your StreamBuilder in a FutureBuilder since it depends on the future `_authService.getUserId()`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 900,
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: _authService.getUserId(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) 
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: fireFirestore.instance.collection('properties').where('uid', isEqualTo: snapshot.data) .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            ...
          },
        );

        return Text('future had no data');
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: jesus man, I lost 2 days on this.. (i'm completly new to flutter) 
i'm probably gonna need this everytime i need for example the users photo and such right? 
You are a live saver and should be given a cookie for sure! Thank you

Comment: @raiton Yes. Anytime your widget depends on the result of some future, think about FutureBuilder. My pleasure, we've all been there.